# Obtain lists of plot marker and line styles in Octave

Tags: plot, octave, linestyle

Is there a way to programmatically obtain the list of marker and line styles available for plotting in Octave?

Ideally, I would do something like

```
mslist = whatever_function_for_marker_styles;
lslist = whatever_function_for_line_styles;
for i = 1:np
    plot(x, y(i,:), 'marker', mslist(i), 'linestyle', lslist(i))
endfor
```

Notes:

1. I would add some `mod` functions to cycle across the lists.
2. I know the size of both lists may not be the same, so they may shift from one another upon cycling.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to get the symbols from the manual and put them in a cell array:

```
mslist = {'+', 'o', '*', '.', 'x', 's', 'd', '^', 'v', '>', '<', 'p', 'h'};

lslist = {'-', '--', ':', '-.'};
```

You can loop over them with a standard for-loop and access them by index using curly brackets, e.g. lslist{i}. The symbols are in Section 15.2.1 of the manual (https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/Two_002dDimensional-Plots.html#Two_002dDimensional-Plots). An ordinary vector would work for mslist instead of a cell array as all the symbols are single characters, but not for lslist where some of them are two characters long.

Comment: Thanks. This option is good, and I did have it in mind. That is why I asked about obtaining the lists programmatically (which I don't know how to do).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Howard that doing it 'entirely' programmatically is probably overkill.

However, if you *do* want to do that, my bet would be to parse the 'help' output for the 'plot' command, which is guaranteed to mention these points, and has a reasonable guarantee that it will remain in the same format even if more markers are added in the future etc.

I won't parse the whole thing, but if you were to do this, you'd probably start like this:

```
plotdoc = help('plot');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[plotdoc_head   , plotdoc_rest] = deal( strsplit( plotdoc     , '     linestyle' ){:} );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[plotdoc_lines  , plotdoc_rest] = deal( strsplit( plotdoc_rest, '     marker'    ){:} );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[plotdoc_markers, plotdoc_rest] = deal( strsplit( plotdoc_rest, '     color'     ){:} );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[plotdoc_colors , plotdoc_rest] = deal( strsplit( plotdoc_rest, '";displayname;"' ){:} );
```

or something along those lines, and then use regexp or strfind / strtoken / strplit creatively to obtain the necessary tokens in each category.